# How can I uncheck all the checkboxes?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to give an option for the user to select another way to proceed with the operation, and they are needed to select just one checkbox for each radio. So how can I get uncheck all the checkbox if the number of checkboxes selected overpass 1?

```
function testaCheck(idMaster){
    var inputs,i,checados=0;    
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");        
    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        if(inputs[i].type=="checkbox"){     
            if(inputs[i].checked==true){
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD'+idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }
        }
    }
    if(checados>1){
        alert("Só pode haver um item selecionado.");    
        document.getElementsByTagName(inputs.checked=false);                    
        return ;
    }
};       

<label class="input-control radio">
    <input type="radio" name="idMAWB" id="idMAWB" value="<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="selecionaMAWB(this.value)">
    <span class="helper"><%=DS_MAWB%></span>
</label>    

<label for="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" id="masterDireto<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="testaCheck(<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>)">
    <span class="helper"> <%=ID_CD_MAWB%> </span>
</label>[layout test][1]
```

Link: [`1`]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynIAR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format your code correctly

```
function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }
            if (checados > 1) {
                uncheckAll(inputs);
            }

        }
    }
};   

function uncheckAll(inputItems){
    alert("Só pode haver um item selecionado.");
    for (i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this Andrew, i'm starting with JS in my internship. I need to uncheck all the boxes, but the last checkbox stay marked with this code.

Comment: Hell yeah all inputs is unchecking before the last if as i want, for now i just need to turn the value of the last checkbox checked (second box clicked) to null. Thanks for help Andrew

Comment: Hey Andrew, thank you so much, finally i got it! For now i can uncheck all of them and set value null before uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set your checkbox.

here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sk5202/e0qmd5La/12/)

```
$("#Allcheck").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: i cannot use this code, you can show me how can i apply in my code? I i'm starting in JS and this is a job of my internship. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }

        }

    }
    if (checados > 1) {
                uncheckAll(inputs);
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = null;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);
            }
};  

function uncheckAll(inputItems){
    alert("Só pode haver um item selecionado. Favor refazer a seleção");
    for (i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for help, here is my final code, where all check can be unchecked and value is set null before uncheck.